# How to search instagram comments containing particular keyword

Tags: perl, api, instagram

I want to search the comments published on any media for any particular key word or combination of few key words. My requirement is to get the comments containing that keyword with the help of API. I went through the documentation of Instagram API there I found that search can be made through hash-tag only and most of the time not necessarily my keyword is a hash-tag. So problem is I want to search though the text. That means if the text containing my keyword then it should return that text else not.

Comment: Despite there not beeing any question here i will go ahead and mention WWW::Mechanize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to search for "keywords", you can only search one hashtag with API, and it searches in photo caption as well as comments.

You will have to use `/media/media-id/comments` API to get all comments, save it and then manually do a search. This is not efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

After you tag your post with a hashtag, you'll be able to tap the hashtag to see a page that shows all photos and videos people have uploaded with that hashtag. There is no API to search for "keywords", you can only search one hashtag with API, and it searches in photo caption as well as comments.

Comment: Which API i can use for searching in Comments, can you please provide me the reference link